# SonarQube API Date+Time Zone not working when using inside spring boot

Tags: java, sonarqube, postman, rest

https://sonarqube.aws.example.com/api/project_analyses/search?from=2020-10-13T19:00:43%2b0530&to=2020-10-14T19:00:43%2b0530&project=project

This api call is working when try using PostMan but when I try to use inside the project its gives me a 400 error `[{"errors":[{"msg":"Date '2020-10-13T19:00:43%2b0530' cannot be parsed as either a date or date+time"}]`

I tried using `URL.encode` to encode the date but when I do that it gives me all the analysis not the specific one.

```
String baseUrl = "https://sonarqube.aws.example.com/api/project_analyses/search?";`
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
String query = "from=2020-10-13T19:00:43+0530&to=2020-10-14T19:00:43+0530&project=project";`
HttpEntity<ResponseAnalysis> responseAnalysisHttpEntity = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + query , HttpMethod.GET, getStringHttpEntity(), ResponseAnalysis.class);`
```

> I get the same above if do like this

Comment: It appears that the `%2b` is not decoded to `+` before attempting to parse as date (i.e. it is encoded "too much"). Have you tried to replace it with `+` instead? In your java code, something probably adds an additional layer of URL encoding.

Comment: Hm ok. Please edit this additional information into your question (you can also format it better there).